# how to change a clusterrole with kubectl gracefully

Tags: kubernetes

By default, the data in clusterrole system:node is as below:

```
$ kubectl get clusterrole system:node -o yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
name: system:node
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods
  verbs:
  - create
  - delete
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods/status
  verbs:
  - patch
  - update
```

Now, I want to change the clusterrole `system:node`, and added a `- patch` under the pods resources, it should be like this:

```
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
  - patch
```

I could update it by using `kubectl edit`, but I want to update it in the bash script, so `kubectl edit` is not suitable, is there any other solution using kubectl?

Answer (score 8):

You can use a `kubectl apply -f node-role.yaml` where `node-role.yaml` contains the yaml definition of the `ClusterRole` with your change included. `kubectl apply` will update the role if it already exists (and create it otherwise).

Answer (score 3):

**chages.yaml**

```
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
  - patch #added
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods
  verbs:
  - create
  - delete
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods/status
  verbs:
  - patch
  - update
```

Use the following bash command to update the `ClusterRole`

```sh
kubectl patch clusterrole system:node  --patch "$(cat changes.yaml)"
```

For more details visit [k8s official documentations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/)

Comment: This deletes all the other rules that are not present in the patch.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind storing the entire manifest, then I recommend Blokje5's answer of using `kubectl apply`. However, if you're looking for a minimal command that doesn't require storing the entire manifest, then you have two options here using `kubectl patch --type 'json'`:

**1 - Use an 'add' operation**

```
kubectl patch clusterrole system:node --type='json' -p='[{"op": "add", "path": "/rules/0", "value":{ "apiGroups": [""], "resources": ["pods"], "verbs": ["get","list","watch","patch"]}}]'
```

This will insert your new rule at the beginning of the array. Since permissions are additive, the role will get the additional permission you want.

**2 - Use a 'replace' operation**

```
kubectl patch clusterrole system:node --type='json' -p='[{"op": "replace", "path": "/rules/0/verbs", "value":["get","list","watch","patch"]}]'
```

This will replace the `verbs` array of the first element in the `rules` array.

---

Here is an explanation as to why these are your only options:

`kubectl patch` can use 3 different patch strategies. It defaults to using the 'strategic' patch.

Elements in the `containers` array of the `Deployment` object have the unique `name` field and so when doing a 'strategic' patch, it will replace the element that matches the unique value of that field.

```
containers:
- name: this-is-unique-and-a-match-will-replace-this
  image: nginx
```

However, elements in the `rules` array of the `ClusterRole` object do not have a field that requires a unique value. And so the 'strategic' patch has no way of knowing which element you want replaced. Therefore, it just replaces the entire array with whatever patch you give it.

Since the 'strategic' patch is not a viable option for you here (unless you're okay with replacing the entire rules array), you have to resort to using the 'json' patch, which allows you to explicitly define array inserts and replaces.

The disadvantage here is that in option 1, you can add permissions, but not remove them as Kubernetes RBAC is purely additive. And in option 2, you must know the index of the element you want to replace.

---

Here are some useful links:

http://jsonpatch.com/

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the simplest automatable way is to add a new rule to the ClusterRole.

Create a file named `append.yaml` with the following content:

```
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods
  verbs:
  - patch
```

Then, append this rule to the existing YAML manifest of the ClusterRole and reapply it with:

```
kubectl apply -f <(cat <(kubectl get clusterrole system:node -o yaml) append.yaml)
```

The new rule will be merged with the other permissions for `pods`, which you can verify with:

```
kubectl describe clusterrole system:node
```

---

The nicest imperative solution would be to [patch](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/) the object with `kubectl patch`, but it doesn't seem to be easily possible:

- If you want to use a [strategic patch](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/#use-a-strategic-merge-patch-to-update-a-deployment): the `rules` array of the ClusterRole object seems to use a *replace* [patch strategy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/#notes-on-the-strategic-merge-patch), that is, the provided patch would just replace the existing array rather being merged with it.
- If you want to use a [JSON patch](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) to add an additional rule: it doesn't seem to be possible to add a deeply structured array element to an existing array.